# Does Django support transactions out of the box?

Tags: django

I have a set of functionalities that are leveraging the the Django management/commands modules to run a bunch of cron jobs that would update the model. However I also need these to execute as all-or-none transactions. Does Django provide a way to define transactions?

Comment: [Yes.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to wrap a chunk of code in a transaction you can use `transaction.atomic` as a decorator or context manager, e.g.,

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def management_command(args):
    # This code executes inside a transaction.
    do_stuff()
```

or

```
def management_command(args):
    # This code executes in autocommit mode (Django's default).
    do_stuff()

    with transaction.atomic():
        # This code executes inside a transaction.
        do_more_stuff()
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly for more details.